# Processing a JSON API Response

Tags: go

Working on my first Go project and I'm having some trouble wrapping my mind around some of the complex data structures. At the moment, I'm [mocking up the response](http://go-proto.robwilkerson.org/demo.json) from an API that will return a JSON object containing 2 properties:

- `columns` contains an array of fields in the order they should be handled
- `data` contains an array of objects containing the properties listed in `columns`

I need to iterate over the `data` array/slice and, within that, iterate over the `columns` array/slice and extract the current property from the current data object. I'm not handling the data structure properly. A lot of trial and error has left me with the following code and enough frustration to decide I simply needed to ask the question.

```
res, err := http.Get("http://roadmap-proto.robwilkerson.org/demo.json")
failOnError(err, "Uh oh")
defer res.Body.Close()

// Decode and process the JSON response
// var v map[string]interface{}
type View struct {
    Columns []string               `"json:columns"`
    Data    map[string]interface{} `"json:data"`
}
v := View{}
json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&v)
log.Printf("[====>] Data: %s", v)
```

The output from `log.Printf()` is this:

```
Data: {[id avatar name email phone address] map[]}
```

The `columns` seems to read okay, but not the data. Ultimately I need to loop over that and write each field to an Excel cell, but so far I can't even get the data to "load" properly.

Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I inadvertently omitted some key info: On any given call to the API, the number and names of the columns may be different. Within a given call, all objects in the `data` array will be the same, but each call could be very, very different. I can't define a static `struct` and have that work.

Comment: If you data is dynamic, use a map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two structs for this:

```
type ColData struct {
    Id      string `json:"id"`
    Avatar  string `json:"avatar"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Email   string `json:"email"`
    Phone   string `json:"phone"`
    Address string `json:"address"`
}

type View struct {
    Columns []string  `json:"columns"`
    Data    []ColData `json:"data"`
}
```

In response to your update:

```
type View struct {
    Columns []string               `"json:columns"`
    Data    map[string]interface{} `"json:data"`
}
```

just needs to become

```
type View struct {
    Columns []string               `"json:columns"`
    Data    []map[string]interface{} `"json:data"`
}
```

to get your data into the struct. Might also be nice to just work with them as `string` or `json.RawMessage` instead of an `interface{}` as well, but I don't really know what you're doing with it/what you could possibly get out.

Comment: Oh, well first off you would get your data out if instead of `Data    map[string]interface{} \`"json:data"\`` you did `Data []map[string]interface{} \`"json:data"\``, you actually have a slice of maps there, not just a map

Comment: One way of using `[]map[string]string` (are all the object values strings?) like @user3591723 suggests would be: https://play.golang.org/p/V8JVfDtynC